# How to calculate Width and Height of Text in WinRT?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How can i calculate the width and height of text in WinRT. I trying by put my text into TextBlock and set properties are fontsize,fontfamily etc. This will be calculate the height and width. But i can't able to get the performance. Is any other way to calculate width and height with better performance? Please suggest any ideas?

Comment: You mean height of the characters on the screen or what? Can you clarify your intended outcome a little bit please? :)

Comment: Yes I need to calculate the width and height of whole charactes.

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the GDI, GDI+ and [FormattedText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.FormattedText%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class are available in WinRT, seems like that DirectX is the only way to go. You may use the [IDWriteTextLayout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316718%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface to do that.

```
Size TextMeasure::Measure(String^ text, String^ fontFamily, float fontSize, Size layoutSize) {
    // Create DWrite Factory
    IDWriteFactory *pDWriteFactory = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = DWriteCreateFactory(
        DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE::DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
        __uuidof(IDWriteFactory),
        reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&pDWriteFactory)
        );
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        throw ref new Exception(hr, "DWriteCreateFactory failed.");
    }

    // Create TextFormat
    IDWriteTextFormat *pDWriteTextFormat = NULL;
    hr = pDWriteFactory->CreateTextFormat(
        fontFamily->Begin(),
        NULL,
        DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT::DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL,
        DWRITE_FONT_STYLE::DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
        DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH::DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
        fontSize,
        L"en-US",
        &pDWriteTextFormat);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        pDWriteFactory->Release();
        throw ref new Exception(hr, "CreateTextFormat failed.");
    }

    // Create TextLayout
    IDWriteTextLayout *pDWriteTextLayout = NULL;
    hr = pDWriteFactory->CreateTextLayout(
        text->Begin(),
        text->Length(),
        pDWriteTextFormat,
        layoutSize.Width,
        layoutSize.Height,
        &pDWriteTextLayout);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        pDWriteTextFormat->Release();
        pDWriteFactory->Release();
        throw ref new Exception(hr, "CreateTextLayout failed.");
    }

    // Get Text Metrics
    DWRITE_TEXT_METRICS textMetrics;
    hr = pDWriteTextLayout->GetMetrics(&textMetrics);

    // Release referances
    pDWriteTextFormat->Release();
    pDWriteTextLayout->Release();
    pDWriteFactory->Release();

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        throw ref new Exception(hr, "GetMetrics failed.");
    }
    return *ref new Size(textMetrics.width, textMetrics.height);
}
```

Note that in order to use the code in a C#/VB/JavaScript, you can put the code in a Runtime component.